# Oracle Trigger with condition old not equal to new ending up with errors PLS-00049, PL/SQL: ORA-00933

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

Assuming am having data on master table called EMPLOYEES with below sample data:

**EMPLOYEES**

```
+--------+----------+
| EMP_ID | EMP_NAME |
+--------+----------+
|    100 | Smith    |
|    200 | Clark    |
+--------+----------+
```

Now if the table is inserted with new data or updated for existing data; then data looks as per below:
**EMPLOYEES**

```
+--------+----------+
| EMP_ID | EMP_NAME |             
+--------+----------+
|    100 | Blake    | <---- UPDATE with different value
|    200 | Clark    | <---- UPDATE with same value
|    300 | Mary     | <---- INSERT
+--------+----------+
```

Where rows with EMP_ID 100 and 200 are update action and EMP_ID with 300 is insert as its new record.

I wrote trigger to capture insert or update changes in EMP_NAME column only if OLD emp_name NOT EQUAL TO NEW emp_name for respective EMP_ID. (I do not want to have duplicate EMP_ID's in my audit table called EMPLOYEE_AUDITS). Below is the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_audits_tr 
INSERT OR UPDATE ON employees 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF ( inserting OR updating AND :old.emp_name <> :new.emp_name ) THEN 
    INSERT INTO employee_audits(emp_id, old_emp_name,new_emp_name) 
                         VALUES(emp_id, :old.emp_name, :new.emp_name ) 
                         WHERE emp_id = :new.emp_id; 
END IF; 
END;
```

Trying to get output on EMPLOYEE_AUDITS as below based on the data provided above
**EMPLOYEE_AUDITS**

```
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
| ID | EMP_ID | OLD_EMP_NAME | NEW_EMP_NAME |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |    100 | Smith        | Blake        |
|  2 |    300 | NULL         | Mary         |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

For next iteration, when EMPLOYEES table is updated again with new data set as below:
**EMPLOYEES**

```
+--------+----------+
| EMP_ID | EMP_NAME |                             
+--------+----------+
|    100 | Karla    | <---- UPDATE with NEW value  
|    200 | Clark    | <---- UPDATE with same value
|    300 | James    | <---- UPDATE with NEW value
|    400 | Sofia    | <---- INSERT                
+--------+----------+
```

EMPLOYEE_AUDITS table should hold values as below:
**EMPLOYEE_AUDITS**

```
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
| ID | EMP_ID | OLD_EMP_NAME | NEW_EMP_NAME |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |    100 | Blake        | Karla        |
|  2 |    300 | Mary         | James        |
|  3 |    400 | NULL         | Sofia        |
+----+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

With the trigger, am getting error as below:

> errors PLS-00049, PL/SQL: ORA-00933

I thank you all in advance and appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Richa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigger code is wrong:

- there's no `BEFORE` keyword in trigger declaration
- you've already said that it will fire before inserting or updating; you don't have to put that into IF as well
- if you do put it there, then be careful: when there are `OR`s, you'll spoil everything if you don't enclose operators into parenthesis. That would be `if (updating or inserting) and (:old.emp_name <> :new.emp_name) then ...`.
- pay attention to NULL values! When you're inserting, there's no OLD value
- there's no `WHERE` clause in `INSERT INTO`
- you missed to populate the `ID` column in the `AUDIT` table; I chose to use a sequence

Combination of what's being said above (especially missing `BEGIN` and superfluous `WHERE`) caused ORA-00933 (SQL command not properly ended) error.

Here's a *full* example:

```
SQL> create table employees (emp_id number, emp_name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into employees
  2  select 100, 'smith' from dual union all
  3  select 200, 'clark' from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> create table employee_audits
  2    (id number, emp_id number, old_emp_name varchar2(20), new_emp_name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq_audit;

Sequence created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace trigger employee_audits_tr
  2    before insert or update on employees
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if nvl(:old.emp_name, '-1') <> nvl(:new.emp_name, '-1')
  6    then
  7       insert into employee_audits
  8         (id, emp_id, old_emp_name, new_emp_name)
  9         values
 10         (seq_audit.nextval, :new.emp_id, :old.emp_name, :new.emp_name);
 11    end if;
 12  end;
 13  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> update employees set emp_name = 'blake' where emp_id = 100;

1 row updated.

SQL> update employees set emp_name = 'clark' where emp_id = 200;

1 row updated.

SQL> insert into employees values (300, 'mary');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From employee_audits;

        ID     EMP_ID OLD_EMP_NAME         NEW_EMP_NAME
---------- ---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1        100 smith                blake
         2        300                      mary

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: keep only one row per employee]**

In my opinion, you shouldn't do that - what kind of audit is it, if you've lost all previous modifications? Anyway, here's the trigger code:

- first it updates a row
- if `EMP_ID` doesn't exist, `UPDATE` won't do anything and `SQL%ROWCOUNT` will be 0
- in that case, `INSERT` a row

.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger employee_audits_tr
  2    before insert or update on employees
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    update employee_audits set
  6      old_emp_name = :old.emp_name,
  7      new_emp_name = :new.emp_name
  8      where emp_id = :new.emp_id ;
  9
 10    if sql%rowcount = 0 then
 11       insert into employee_audits (id, emp_id, old_emp_name, new_emp_name)
 12       values (seq_audit.nextval, :new.emp_id, :old.emp_name, :new.emp_name);
 13    end if;
 14  end;
 15  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot. I highly appreciate your help. Thank you so much for detailed explanation, for re-writing the code and for saving lot of time for me. I wrote code with AFTER insert statement and I think when formatting I might have deleted. My bad. I have question: if I have to add another column say  "PAYMENT_HOLD" on EMPLOYEES table with Y and N values and if I have to capture these changes on EMPLOYEE_AUDITS table, I must modify just the IF part right? As below:`if ((nvl(:old.emp_name, '-1') <> nvl(:new.emp_name, '-1')) or (nvl(:old.payment_hold, '-1') <> nvl(:new.payment_hold, '-1')))`

Comment: You're welcome. As of a new condition, yes - if you want to check it, use OR.

Comment: Awesome @Littlefoot. Thank you again for quick reply. I highly appreciate your time and help

Comment: No problem at all :)

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, I tried few iterations with different data set and noticed that, am getting duplicate EMP_ID as the condition is specified for insert statement. Should I include update statement if emp_id already exists? I need only unique emp_id inside EMPLOYEES_AUDIT table. Should I modify code as `BEGIN... IF insert then... IF nvl(:old.emp_name, '-1') <> nvl(:new.emp_name, '-1') then.. insert into...` IF updating then `IF update then... nvl(:old.emp_name, '-1') <> nvl(:new.emp_name, '-1') then.. update where...` Am sorry for asking too many questions

Comment: getting error
`create or replace trigger employee_audits_tr
after insert or update on employees
for each row
begin
if (inserting and (nvl(:old.emp_name, '-1') <> nvl(:new.emp_name, '-1')))
then
insert into employee_audits
(id, emp_id, old_emp_name, new_emp_name)
values
(seq_audit.nextval, :new.emp_id, :old.emp_name, :new.emp_name);
end if;
if (updating and (nvl(:old.emp_name, '-1') <> nvl(:new.emp_name, '-1')))
then
update employee_audits
         set old_emp_name = :old.emp_name, new_emp_name = :new.emp_name
         where emp_id = :new.emp_id
    end if;
  end;`

Comment: (Sorry, went to sleep; it was kind of late in my part of the world). Error you got is because you didn't terminate the last UPDATE statement (there's no semi-colon after `:new.emp_id`). I've edited my answer and added some more info. Have a look, please.

Comment: your question makes perfect sense tht if I don't keep track of changes what kind of audit is that. I do not know wht terminology to use but for my requirement, all I need to know is, for particular emp_id if emp_name changes then keep latest changes. I used emp_id and emp_name as an example & for easier understanding.Actually am working on different data set.The reason why I wanted this logic is because based on the data in EMPLOYEE_AUDITS, am sending email to new_emp whenever there's change in old_emp_name and new_emp_name i.e., only on the latest changes & not historical changes.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot. I added IF condition and modified code as below:
`create or replace trigger employee_audits_tr
before insert or update on employees
for each row
begin
if nvl(:old.emp_name, '-1') <> nvl(:new.emp_name, '-1') then
update employee_audits set
old_emp_name = :old.emp_name,
new_emp_name = :new.emp_name
where emp_id = :new.emp_id ;
if sql%rowcount = 0 then
insert into employee_audits (id, emp_id, old_emp_name, new_emp_name)
values (seq_audit.nextval, :new.emp_id, :old.emp_name, :new.emp_name);
end if;
end if;
end;` 
Its working fine.

Comment: Nice; I'm glad you made it.